# Vectorizing a Rolling Window Calculation

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

In MATLAB for loops are sometimes *wildly* inefficient for long term calculations. In my use case, I have ~12,000 observations. I'd like to fit a model every N steps to predict the N+1th step (since the underlying process tends to change in that period).

With a for loop, I would do it like so

```
for i=1:(numel(data) - N)
  pred = fitAndPredict(data(i:i + N - 1));
  // ... store the prediction somewhere
end
```

However you can imagine if the `fitAndPredict` function uses a particularly involved estimation process this loop could run slow. This slowness will be compounded by the for loop being non-optimal. Given that the `fitAndPredict` method takes up the majority of time, I'd prefer to remove the for loop entirely and allow MATLAB to use the vectorized version in order to marginally improve my run time.

I cannot for the life of me come up with a way to vectorize a rolling window. My best guess is to create a vector of the pre-calculated rolling windows, and then run a function for each one using `arrayfun` - but this still seems non-optimal. I'm not positive but wouldn't `arrayfun` still require a loop under the hood?

Has anyone encountered this and solved it elegantly? I'd love to hear how to solve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: The answer depends on what happens inside fitAndPredict. That's the function where you want to vectorize the code.

Comment: It's a simple nonseasonal ARIMA model

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that is. But you need to look at that code and think about how you'd implement it if the input were a matrix where the columns (or rows) are the windows it's operating on. Your idea of pre-computing those windows is right.

Comment: Have you profiled the for-loop version to see where it's spending its time? If the slow bit is fitting the model, it probably won't make much difference whether the model input comes from a for loop or not. I'm not expert on ARIMA but maybe you can find an algorithm that applies it to streaming data, with a fixed time window? Otherwise the best way to speed up this code would probably be to parallelise it, which shouldn't be hard but you need to have the parallel computing toolbox.